# How to qualify a command with a module name containing a dash?

Tags: powershell, syntax, module, command

**In PowerShell, how do you qualify the name of a command (in an invocation) with the name of a module that contains a dash?**

Specifically, I am trying to invoke `posh-git\Write-VcsStatus`, but the interpreter does not recognize this as a module-qualified command. I have already imported the `posh-git` module; my `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` is defaulted to `All` anyway; and I have verified that my installed version of `posh-git` contains the command `Write-VcsStatus`. This issue lies in contrast to other examples that do work in my same environment, e.g. `PowerLine\New-PromptText`.

---

For reference, my `$PSVersionTable` is as follows:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.0
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763 
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to the presence of `-` ([HYPHEN-MINUS, `U+002D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d)) in the module name, as evidenced by the fact that invoking `posh-git\Write-GitStatus` works.

Instead, the problem is that the [`posh-git` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-git) is defined in a nonstandard way:

As of module versions 0.7.3, exported function `Write-VcsStatus` is defined as follows:

```
function Global:Write-VcsStatus { # ...
```

That is, the function is placed in the *global scope*, which means that it technically *isn't part of the module at runtime* (despite being listed as an exported function and even tab-completion thinking it is a regular part of the module).

Therefore, you can only invoke it *without* the module qualifier `posh-git\`, either as `Write-VcsStatus` or, unambiguously, as `global:Write-VcsStatus`.

I can't speak to *why* the function is declared this way - the underlying [GitHub repo](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) provides no clue at first glance, but you could consider creating an issue there.